# How to reverse the quotes of my Urdu sentence?

Tags: regex

I have lots of text in `Urdu` language which has quotes reversed. I want to reverse them back to normal.

```
 ’’احرام باندھتے وقت کاغسل‘‘
```

This is what it looks like (above). I want to make it look like this:

```
‘‘احرام باندھتے وقت کاغسل’’
```

If you see closely the quotes given above are double single quotes to make it look like double-quotes. I need a regular expression code for this. The code which I am using is not working as expected.

I am using `(\x{2019}{2})(.+?)(\x{2018}{2})` for find and replacing as `$3$2$1`

I actually want a typographer's quote / curly quote.

**Note:** I wanted to show the image but for some reason, I am not able to upload the image here.

Comment: You can post a link to an image if you want.

Comment: What regex flavour are you using (e.g. PCRE, BRE, Python...), and/or what software or what programming language (e.g. Notepad++, PowerShell, ...) are you trying to use it in?

Comment: Actually I am using Adobe Indesign Grep feature. I have observed that Notepad++ regex works in Indesign. I have have also found that (*SKIP)(*FAIL) also works. I dont know which flavour exactly this is.

Link to Image

[link](https://www.mediafire.com/file/2ymi6r7emt8bavu/required.png/file)

Thanks

Comment: Works for me, [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/61Zxs1/1). Is your file UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: Yes Toto, my text is UTF-8 encoded. Actually I am looking for a better grep code. In my text there are some sentences which have only opening quotes or only closing quotes. The above code is creating problem there I guess. 
Thanks

Comment: And with what type of quotes do you want to replace a match if there is only a opening quote?